# PerformancePoint webpart showing report from Reporting Service, but is showing cached content!

Tags: reporting-services, cache

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have created some reporting service report. On some page, I have created the PerformancePoint webpart to show the reporting service report. It works and shows content. But when I change the data and go again to the page with the performancePoint webpart, it shows the old content. It looks like it shows the cached content. When I open this page on another tab I have the same issue. When open a private session it works fine, I can see the latest content.

It looks like there is some caching on the session.

How can I fix this reporting service caching issue?

ps. I have turned off the toolbar from this report

Answer (score 0):

Under the Data Source for report in Dashboard Designer there is a default cache setting.

[image]
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2010/04/16/a-general-caching-overview-for-performance-point-services-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

You may also want to verify that the report is not set to be cached in the reporting services configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've found deleting the web part and recreating it is one of the quickest ways to deal with the cached results.